# Looking for data on river flow speeds

Tags: data, hydrology, rivers, flow

I'm looking for sources containing data on measured river flow speeds, any / all locations worldwide, in any format or language.

Googling didn't help much.

Comment: It will be very difficult to obtain such a dataset worldwide, generally River flow speeds are measured at discharge stations or weather stations that are controlled by Research organizations or Government Organizations. Your best bet would to look for some way to get the flow speeds with Remote Sensing (or something that gets the flow speed indirectly).

Comment: If you are ever looking for open data then don't forget about the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

According to a post in [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_database_providing_the_flow_velocity_of_each_river_globally) there is a Brazilian website which may hold river flow velocities in a "National Information System on Water Resources" dataset although I cannot confirm this. The following is the link posted from ResearchGate. Also, how's your Portuguese?

http://www2.snirh.gov.br/home/